# What is an isolated subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, valuation-theory, infinitesimals, ordered-groups

" As in the case of finite numbers, the infinitesimal numbers form an isolated subgroup  of $R_{inf}$ of $^*R$"[page 152](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X7590013X)

What does this sentence mean? What is an isolated subgroup?

Comment: Where did you find this sentence?

Comment: @Shaun   page 152 of:  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022314X7590013X

Comment: Your question is receiving downvotes because you haven't provided sufficient context in  the question. At the very minimum, whenever you include a quote, you should provide a reference to the source of the quote (in the question, not the comments).

Comment: Regarding the previous comment of @AlexKruckman, take a look at our guidelines for [formatting and writing your question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992), under the subheading "Make your question visible, searchable, accessible".

Comment: @AlexKruckman Sorry.... I really have to learn this...

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full quote reads:

> As in the case of finite numbers, the infinitesimal numbers form an isolated subgroup $\mathbf{R}_{\text{inf}}$ of $^*\mathbf{R}$; this implies that the factor group $^*\mathbf{R}/\mathbf{R}_{\text{inf}}$ inherits naturally its order relation from $^*\mathbf{R}$.

From this context, I would infer that for an ordered group $(G,\leq)$, a subgroup $H$ is isolated if for all $x,y\in H$, if $z\in G$ with  $x\leq z \leq y$, then $z\in H$. This condition is necessary and sufficient for the ordering  $\leq$ on $G$ to induce an ordering on the quotient group $G/H$. And the infinitesimal numbers certainly  satisfy this condition.

I have never heard the term "isolated" used in this way - I would call such a  subgroup $H$ "convex". The very first Google result for "isolated subgroup" is this page: https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Isolated_subgroup. Here *Encyclopedia of Math* gives a different (non-order-theoretic) definition. But it also notes

> In the theory of ordered groups, isolated subgroups are sometimes referred to as convex subgroups.

This is a bit odd: it's clear that a convex subgroup of an ordered group is isolated (by the EOM definition), but it seems to me that there are isolated subgroups  of ordered groups  which are not convex  (e.g. $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$  as additive groups). But in any case, it seems relatively clear that "isolated" means "convex" in the context of the paper  you're reading.